# Having problems with my header and <div> not aligning

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to web development and I'm making a website for a club at my school. It's http://crsclub.org

I am trying to get the header text to be centered in the whole page in the top div, without it acknowledging the picture at all. I got the main text there and from what I see, I thought that everything else would go too.

Basically, the text underneath Computer Repair and Share Club should all be centered underneath it, the 'of Manchester Community College' and all of the links.

I WAS using tables for everything but the code was very messy and my friends told me to never use tables for this sort of thing.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my header.php (included on every page on my site with php include)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CRS Club <?php echo $page; ?></title>
<script src="/resources/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/konami.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="boxed_header disable-select" style="float:center;">
<div class="absolute" style="float:left; width:20%">
    <img src="http://crsclub.org/images/logo.png" height="142" width="142" />
</div>

<div class="absolute center">
<div style="width:80%">
<h1>Computer Repair and Share Club</h1>
<h4>of Manchester Community College</h4>
</div>
<div style="width:80%">
<a align=center href="http://crsclub.org">Home</a> | <a align=center href="http://crsclub.org/links.php">Links</a> | <a href="http://crsclub.org/events.php">Events</a> | <a href="http://crsclub.org/contact.php">Contact Us</a> | <a href="http://crsclub.org/diagnostics.php">Self-Help</a> | <a href="http://crsclub.org/services.php">Our Services</a>
</div>
</div></div>

<xfs class="disable-select">
<br></xfs>
```

here is my CSS

```
body {background-color: #454079;}<!--#161058!-->

/*Header properties, Absolute keeps items in any position on page.*/
.absolute {
position:absolute;}
td{min-width:142px;}
.center {margin:auto;}

/*Disable header dragging mess.*/
.disable-select {-webkit-user-select: none;  
-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;}
img {pointer-events: none;}

/*Fonts*/
p.sansserif{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}

/*For bottom content boxes.*/
div.content{width:60%;
min-width:420px;
border:solid 2px #1A1A1A;
border-radius:5px;
padding:10px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#F1F1F1;}
.border{border:solid 1px #000000;}

/*Link formatting.*/
.lks {text-align: center;}
a:link {color:blue;text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {color:blue;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {color:#00008A;}

/*Table formatting.*/
h1 {color:black; text-align:center; vertical-align:text-top; font-family:verdana; font-size:28; }
td {vertical-align: top;}
table {background-color: #F1F1F1}
.boxed_header {border:2px solid #a1a1a1;padding:10px 40px; 
background:#F1F1F1;border-radius:14px;}
.boxed_body {border:0px solid #a1a1a1;background:#F1F1F1;width:50%;border-radius:14px;margin:auto;}
```

fiddle with:
http://jsfiddle.net/9FkK4/

I've honestly tried a lot and I've put in a lot of hours and I can't figure it out.

Also, this was my old header which looks just the way I want it to look on the client side but is very messy with tables.

```
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" height="142" width="142"/></a>
</td>
<td width=100% align=center>
<h1>Computer Repair and Share Club</h1>
<a align=center href="index.php">Home</a> | <a align=center href="links.php">Links</a> | <a href="events.php">Events</a> | <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a> | <a href="diagnose.php">Diagnostics</a> | <a href="services.php">Our Services</a>
</td></tr></table>
<hr>
</body>
```

Comment: When asking such question: besides posting the markup _always_ also provide a fiddle with the same code for others to simply play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Have you tried stripping down your HTML and CSS a little until you got a minimal page that still reproduces the problem? JSFiddle is a great tool to help you with that.

Comment: Try `<div style="width:100%">` instead of `<div style="width:80%">` above `<h1>Computer Repair and Share Club</h1>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the div above your h1 to 100% and add text-align:center;
I think you should learn some more markup before you really publish this project.